# i3wm: Screenshot script fails if bound to key

Tags: imagemagick, i3-window-manager

imagemagick's `import` shell command takes snapshots of ones desktop. Executing

```
import /tmp/foo.png
```

will convert my cursor into a crosshair and will allow me to select a screen area to capture. However, if I attempt to bind that very command to an i3wm-hotkey it does not work.

The following keybind in my i3wm config file

```
# ...
bindsym $mod+m exec "import /tmp/foo.png"
# ...
```

produces the following error (which I can pipe out to a terminal):

> *import-im6.q16: unable to grab mouse `': No such file or directory @ error/xwindow.c/XSelectWindow/9187.*

Why is that and how can I make it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that the keybinding will fire as soon as you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>. Add `--release` to the `bindsym` call to make it fire when you release the key and it will work:

```
bindsym --release $mod+m exec "import /tmp/foo.png"
```

This has even been [documented](https://i3wm.org/docs/userguide.html#keybindings):

> Some tools (such as import or xdotool) might be unable to run upon a
>   KeyPress event, because the keyboard/pointer is still grabbed. For
>   these situations, the --release flag can be used, which will execute
>   the command after the keys have been released.

Comment: That is terrific. Thank you very much. I went right by that section of the documentation multiple times.